# Wiring views in MVVM Light for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

If I have a MainView for now, and inside MainView i have a stackpanel. And now what I want is to plug different views based on Menu item click. How to implement this using MVVM Light?

Would be great if somebody can post a link to a project sample with code or video!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about MVVM light, but I do something like that without this Light framework as follows:

```
<!-- Content area that contains user controls for all wizard steps -->
    <Grid Margin="0,3,0,0">
        <Views:CustomerSelection Visibility="{Binding Path=IsCustomerSelectionVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Views:CustomerInformation Visibility="{Binding Path=IsCustomerInformationVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Views:CustomerPreferences Visibility="{Binding Path=IsCustomerPreferencesVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Views:ProjectSelection Visibility="{Binding Path=IsProjectSelectionVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Views:KitchenProjectPreferences Visibility="{Binding Path=IsKitchenProjectPreferencesVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Views:OtherProjectProperties Visibility="{Binding Path=IsOtherProjectPropertiesVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
```

And in the underlying viewmodel I just set the appropriate properties for making one of the usercontrols visible.

Comment: looks good, but do you load all views and their components initially?

Comment: in my case yes, because I have one underlying viewmodel with two subviewmodels; and they encaspulate two domain objects that were already loaded. I don't know in your case. you may choose to delay the loading of data in your viewmodels until they become visible, if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do this is, define all view's datatemplates in mainview.
and then have a itemscontrol(bind it to mainviewmodel's collection of viewmodels property)

Now based on menuitem click, clear that viewmodels collection and add the required view.